Which numeral system is taught at schools in China?
I developed a mobile application for practicing multiplication tables. Below is the notation that I currently use for German and English calculations:
 2 ×  2 =   4
 3 ×  2 =   6
...
10 × 20 = 200

I now want to translate it to Chinese to also publish the application within China. From what I read, there are different numeral systems used in China. I found images like this:

On the other hand, it seems like Chinese pupils also learn to read arabic numbers. It does not clarify though whether that includes the multiplication sign × and the equals sign =.
Which numeral system would be more appropriate and common to use in such an educational mobile application?

Try do a search on "九九乘法表", it was the multiplication/numerical system I was taught.

Why it makes sense if read from right to left.

Using Chinese characters in that context would be like writing "two × two = four" instead of "2 × 2 = 4" in English.

As @r13 said in comment, your application is similar to 九九乘法表. Here is an example.
In 九九乘法表, equations are usually written with Arabic numerals but read in Chinese (that is, you don’t need to translate unless you really want to teach users how to read). The way to read is slightly different from the general way of reading equations to make them easy to memorize. More specifically, if the product is

Greater than 10: We don’t read the x and = signs for speed. For example, 3x7=21  is read as 三七二十一 (三 is 3, 七 is 7, 二十一 is 21).
Equal to 10: I read it as 二五一十 (this is different from 二五得十 in my link above, but it’s not a big deal).
Less than 10: We say 得 for = for rhythm, otherwise it’s too short compared to the other equations. For example, 2x3=6 is read as 二三得六 (二 is 2, 三 is 3, 得 is =, 六 is 6).

The way of reading can vary with time and location. Your image is a very old version of 九九乘法表. So old that the characters are still written from right to left, and 得 is the original version of 如.
If your table of equations stops at 9x9, it’s called 九九乘法表 or 小九九 (small 九九). If it stops at 19x19, it’s sometimes called 大九九 (big 九九). 大九九 is not very common, and I don’t know a standard way of reading it.

Chinese have adopted the mathe system the same as the rest of the world, they use Arabic numerals (1, 2, 3...), and the modern math operators (+, -, x, /, =, ...), but they do preserve their traditional expressions as shown below.
Basic Math Operations: (words in boldface are math operators)

2 + 2 = 4  - 二加二等于四

3 - 2 = 1 - 三減二等于一

10 x 21 = 210 - 十乘二十等于二百一(十)

360/2 = 180 - 三百六(十)除二等于一百八(十)


The Chinese numeral in ( ) is optional -  二百一十 = 二百一 = 210
Chinese Numerals:
一,二,三,四,五,六,七,八,九,十 = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
十ㄧ,十二,.....十九,二十 = 11,12,....19,20
Units of larger numbers - 百,千,万,亿 = hundred, thousand, ten thousand,  hundred million

Even though, Chinese language have their own characters but it seems to be de facto standard to use Arabic numerals (1,2,3…). So, in Chinese the table would be written in the same way but of course would be read in different way. As you can watch here and here , only numbers are pronounced and not x and = signs.
